# aws ec2 ubuntu require my password

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

i want to build a project and failed because it requires root permission. When i change the user to root as "sudo -s", it prompted `[sudo] password for ubuntu`.  As ec2 doesn't offer ubuntu password, it login with pem file. How can I login as root and create files? Thanks!

Comment: Do you fix this issue?

Answer (score 14):

I fixed this by doing using "sudo" for a Ubuntu AWS EC2 SSH Login:

```
$ sudo passwd ubuntu
```

Instead of prompting me for:

```
"(current) UNIX password:"
```

It prompts now for:

```
"Enter new UNIX password:"
```

I hope this fixes some problems with ec2 ubuntu users!

Comment: Picked up AWS after a while, and created an ubuntu instance. I was installing brew, but it would keep asking for a password. AWS documentation won't provide any solution. After 1.5 hours found this solution, and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I was surprised as well, when AWS ec2 ubuntu prompted me for a password.

```
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
```

In the end I just hit  <kbd>return</kbd> without inserting anything and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run commands from your terminal interactively as root do it as follows:

```
sudo -i
```

If just want to run a single command do it as:

```
sudo some-command-goes-here
```

**You will not be prompted for password in any of these scenario.**

Comment: i changed to root by `su root`

Answer (score 0):

AWS doesn't grant root access by default to EC2 instances. This is an important security best practise. Users are supposed to open a ssh connection using the secure key/pair to login as ec2-user. Users are supposed to use the sudo command as ec2-user to obtain elevated privileges.